# How to get the selected radio button value inside the form from expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating an Application using Expressjs,
My Jade code,

```
form(method='post', action='/listJobs')
  each item in myJobNames
    input(type='radio', name='jobNameRadio', val='#{item}')
    | #{item}
    br
```

My post handler,

```
cur_Job = req.body.jobNameRadio;
req.session.cur_Job = cur_Job;
console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.session.cur_Job);
```

But in console.log, I am getting this.

> { jobNameRadio: 'on' } on

How to get the value of the selected radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `val` to `value` and the correct answer will appear in `jobNameRadio`

```
form(method='post', action='/listJobs')
  each item in myJobNames
    input(type='radio', name='jobNameRadio', value='#{item}')
    | #{item}
    br
```

Then use

```
console.log(req.body.jobNameRadio);
```

If no correct values are provided, you get on when something is selected, or nothing when not.